# how many types we can use the word dog

Tags: grammar, sentence

There are various set expressions, idioms or merely collocations, which include the lexeme 'dog' – such as 'a dog's life' and 'every dog has its day'.

What other expressions including this lexeme are there, may I ask?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I always wonder what drives people to ask "how many" questions about language. First of all, more often than not it is impossible to tell. Secondly and more importantly, that information is utterly useless trivia, is it not. So what if we knew for a fact, which we don't, that there are 148 idioms involving *dog*, or 184, or 841.

Comment: So OP is barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: That's another excellent point. Barking up the wrong tree clearly doesn't involve a dog, and yet it clearly does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk) to search for *dog*. There are **963 results.**

> top dog
>   dog days
>   dog in the manger
>   ...